# React stripe, The PaymentIntent requires a payment method

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, strapi

I'm trying to create a stripe payment in a react app with a strapi back end.

I'm been using different tutorial but now I'm stuck at the final stage

This code creates a Payment intent created successfully but in stripe it creates an incomplete payment

Stripe states

> The PaymentIntent requires a payment method
>
> Set an existing payment method on the PaymentIntent or have the customer enter a new payment method.

but I still can't work out what the payment method should be

here is the code I have for stripe

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useAppContext } from '../context/AppContext'


const NewCheckOut = () => {
    const { cart } = useAppContext()
    console.log('---cart---', cart)
    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()

    const [token, setToken] = useState('')
    const [total, setTotal] = useState('loading')

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const cardElement = elements?.getElement(CardElement);

        if (!stripe || !cardElement) {
            // Handle error, either stripe or cardElement is not available
            return;
        }
        console.log('handleSubmit', e)
        const result = await stripe?.confirmCardPayment(data.paymentIntent.client_secret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    name: 'John',
                    email: 'John@site.co.uk'
                }
            }
        })
        console.log('---handleSubmit---', result)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadToken = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/orders/payment', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    cart: cart.items
                })
            })
            const data = await response.json()
            console.log('---token---', data)
            setToken(data.paymentIntent.client_secret)
            setTotal(data.amount)
        }

        loadToken()
    }, [cart])

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Total: {total}</h3>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <CardElement options={{ hidePostalCode: true }} />
                <button>Buy It</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewCheckOut
```

The console.log for handelsubmit `console.log('---handleSubmit---', result)` produces

```
{
  error: "resource_missing",
  doc_url: "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
  message: "No such payment_intent: 'pi_************'",
  param: "intent",
  request_log_url: "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_**************",
  type: "invalid_request_error",
  // other properties if any
}
```

Comment: usually the most common reason for `No such....` errors is that one of the API keys is from a different (wrong Stripe account). Have you validated if both your secret and publishable keys are correct (and from the same Stripe account)?